# ToolStripTextBox image is not appearing

Tags: vb.net, forms, menu, menustrip

I am using WindowsForms and I am trying to put a Textbox into my main menu and add an Image. However I cannot get the image to appear. What am I missing here.

```
txtRequestEdit.DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.ImageAndText
txtRequestEdit.Image = Properties.Resources.Wrench16 'This is a valid image.
```

txtRequestEdit is a System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripTextBox

EDIT- Here is an image of the menu. The item at the bottom of this menu is the txtRequestEdit control.

[image]

Comment: do you get text but no image?

Comment: Yes. The textbox shows up and functions correctly. But the image that should show up to the left of it does not appear.

Comment: Just to clarify, you configured the DisplayStyle in the properties window or you're doing it in code? I ask because according to documentation, DisplayStyle isn't relevant to ToolStripTextBox.

Comment: I added the DisplayStyle in code in an attempt to get the image to appear, but it did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely the no matter how you apply the image, it won't show on `ToolStripTextBox`. I think this is a bug because I found nothing about this behavior in the documents or on the web.

I will try doing this with a hack like owner-drawing the item or something else and will put the wrong answer here so the next person with this issue avoids this wrong path.

**This is wrong:**

Apparently the `Image` property "supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.", so if (as you say) everything's OK and you've checked the image itself to be valid, using `ImageList` and `ImageIndex` may solve the problem (assuming the item lies inside a `MenuStrip` named `menuStrip1`:

```
txtRequestEdit.DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.ImageAndText
menuStrip1.ImageList = New ImageList()
menuStrip1.ImageList.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.Wrench16)
txtRequestEdit.ImageIndex = 0
```

Comment: I am unable to access ImageList property on txtRequestEdit (ToolStripTextBox). "Cannot resolve symbol 'ImageList'"

Comment: Sorry I don't know what was I thinking at the moment! I'll take a look and be back

Comment: Maybe putting an Image on a ToolStripTextBox is not supported. But I cant confirm that anywhere.

Comment: This makes me angry! No one mentioned anything about this. It is there and just not working. Even using owner drawing and `ToolStripRenderer` I can't put that image there. I should go to sleep for now, but I will find the reason after de-compiling the library tomorrow and post the results here :)